# Laravel sqlite relative path

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I want to deploy my application in multiple pc's and it's using sqlite for db.
Is there any way to set a relative path instead of an absolute one in my env file?
Is there any alternative to sqlite to have portable database?

Example is there anyway to use something like this:

```
DB_DATABASE=${ variable/to/database/folder }/database.sqlite
```

Instead of:

```
DB_DATABASE=C:\wamp64\www\JUICE\projects\my-project\database\database.sqlite
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First step comment out DB_DATABASE in .env:

```
#DB_DATABASE=homestead
```

Second, check you have this in `config/database.php`, it's the code that ships with laravel:

```php
'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
```

And you have your database path relative to your application root and changing with the application directory because you rely on the path helper `database_path()`.

I can't give you any alternative, I use `sqlite` for local development with satisfaction.

Answer (score 4):

The default database configuration already includes a relative path to the database file for sqlite

```php
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

Now to use your `.env` variable to rename the file but keep a relative path you can do this

`.env`

```
DB_DATABASE=different-name.sqlite
```

`config/database.php`

```php
'database' => database_path(env('DB_DATABASE')),
```

> Is there any alternative to sqlite to have portable database?

- You can export any database like MySQL as a `.sql` file populated with data and push it to your git repo
- Another way would be with [Redis](https://redis.io) using a [Python Script](https://github.com/p/redis-dump-load#command-line-usage)

```bash
# dump database 0
./redisdl.py > dump.json
./redisdl.py -o dump.json

# load into database 0
./redisdl.py -l < dump.json
./redisdl.py -l dump.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the below works for the latest version of Laravel.

In config/database.php, amend the database key/value pair using the database_path() helper:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

Answer (score 0):

tested with **Windows & Laravel 10** run **pwd** command to get full path then create sqlite file inside database folder.

env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=E:\WebProjects\myProject/database/database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```